# Find java version of jdk available in shared path

Tags: java, windows, shared-directory

I want to find the version of the JDK available in a shared path. The folder name of the JDK is - jsdk. I don't have access to control panel or command prompt of the remote server. Is there a way to find the version of java in these cases?

Comment: Are you able to run code on the server?

Comment: You mean to say read 1.7.0_40 from installed JAVA folder like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40` ?

Comment: I want the result of "java -version" command. As i dont have access to command prompt how can i get the java version?

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way.

In fact, I'm having difficulty think of any way that is guaranteed to work for you.

- The obvious (supported) ways would be to run `java -version`, or run a Java class that interrogates the system properties.  But you can't run `java` on the system.
- Or you could try to look inside one of the system JAR files.  But you can't run the `jar` command on the system.
- Or you could look in the Registry (maybe).  But that requires a command prompt on the system.

The best I can come up with is:

1. copy the `jre/lib/rt.jar` file to some system or place where you *can* run the `jar` command.
2. use `jar` to extract `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
3. parse the `MANIFEST.MF` file to extract the value of the `Implementation-Version` attribute.

I think that should work for any recent Oracle or OpenJDK JRE.

---

(Or if you want to be really, really crude, `strings rt.jar | grep 1.7.0_65 | less` ... repeated for all of the version strings that you are interested in.)